# Список дат в заданном интервале

Tags: php

*Доброго времени суток.* Ребят, помогите пожалуйста сделать функцию, которая будет возвращать список дат, которые находятся в определенном промежутке.
Например, есть две переменные date1 = дата начала и date2 = дата окончания. Нужна функция, которая будет возвращать промежуток всех этих дат.
Опять же пример, `date1 = 8.12.2013` и `date2 = 12.12.2013`, функция нам вернет:

```
8.12.2013, 9.12.2013, 10.12.2013, 11.12.2013, 12.12.2013.
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А у вас есть какие нибудь идеи о том, как это сделать?

[][1]

[1]: http://ideone.com/RDul9G

Comment: А каков будет диапазон? В пределах месяца, года, больше? (1) Делать исключительно средствами mysql или php+mysql? (2). Метод простой -- создаётся таблица (можно временная) с календарём для подходящего периода и из неё выбираются даты в указанном диапазоне.

Comment: Не совсем понятно какие отношения между php и mysql здесь. На mysql - выборка between (с возможным преобразованием поля через date()):

    select mydate from mytable where mydate between date('2013-12-01') and date('2013-12-12')

На php - смотреть в сторону DateTime.

Comment: В дальнейшем я сам прикручу все это к mySQL, сейчас же мне нужна функция, которая с помощью PHP будет выводить список дат определенного промежутка.
Я лишь указываю любые date1 и date2 и выводом получаю список.
На счет диапазона, то он будет разный (к примеру 5 дней или же 55 дней).


PS:
date1 = 8.12.2013 и date2 = 12.12.2013, функция нам вернет:
8.12.2013, 9.12.2013, 10.12.2013, 11.12.2013, 12.12.2013.

Comment: На PHP так на PHP :-) Например (вариантов куча):

    $date_fmt = 'd.m.Y';
    $start_fmt = '8.12.2013';
    $date_start = date_create_from_format( $date_fmt, $start_fmt );
    while( $start_fmt != '12.12.2013' )
    {
        print "$start_fmt\n";
        $date_start = date_modify( $date_start, '+1 day' );
        $start_fmt = date_format($date_start, $date_fmt);
    }
    print "$start_fmt\n";

Comment: [Function to generate array of dates between two dates (date range array)](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php#100733)

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться предопределенными календарными классами PHP

```
<?php
// Дата начала интервала
$start = new DateTime("8.12.2013");
// Дата окончания интервала
$end = new DateTime("12.12.2013");
// Интервал в один день
$step = new DateInterval('P1D');
// Итератор по дням
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $step, $end);

// Вывод дней
foreach($period as $datetime) {
  echo $datetime->format("j.m.Y")."<br />";
}
```